# Function testing tool for c,c++,c#

Tags: c#, c++, c, testing

Is there any testing tool for c,c++ or c#, other than debugging, which works like copying-pasting an independent function to some text box, and entering parameters on other text boxes?

Comment: Do you mean unit testing? this has to be done by you, you can create a few tests for your methods.

Comment: Are the c/c++ methods you want to test implemented as exports?

Comment: As @Xtian commented, what you really want is unit testing. That way you make the effort once and reap the benefits there after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you think about unit testing.  I recommend you  Google Test and Google Mock. It is simple and powerful tool (and for free!).

http://code.google.com/p/googletest/

http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/

There are some clear examples and very easy to read documentations.

After you create unit test you have possibility to refactor your code in easy way. After yo change sth unit test will fail. There is a lot of different solution like boost tests etc.

After few weeks with UT you will be not able to life without them.

Programming is really less stressful.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), which allows you to quickly and easily execute arbitrary C# code.

Comment: I know it doesn't. I was being polite!